# I've been asked to learn function compositions. I am lost how to find (f ∘ g)(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

I am trying to combine functions.  My dad explained that he cannot answer and maybe I should track math stack overflow.  I am not sure exactly how to type the questions because the keyboard doesn't have all the math symbols.  My online class doesn't allow copy and paste either.  I will try.

I am trying to find $(f \circ g)(x)$ where

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3},$$

$$g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}.$$

My lesson said that  (f o g)(x) (the o looks like a degree sign, but placed down lower. My keyboard will not allow me to type the actual symbol) f(g(x)), but I don't understand how to use this formula to solve the problem, and my lesson isn't explaining very well either.

I'm hoping somebody can help me out with this and I can actually interact with them to figure out how to do this.

(I am in tenth grade, precal algebra. Attached is a screenshot of the problem that I am trying to solve.)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{1. }&\text {Find }(f \circ g)(x) \text { where } f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{2}+3} \text { and } g(x)=\sqrt{x-2} \text {. }\\
&\text{a. }(f \circ g)(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}\\
&\text{b. }(f \circ g)(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}+3}\\
&\text{c. }(f \circ g)(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}\\
&\text{d. }(f \circ g)(x)=\sqrt{\frac{-2 x^{2}-5}{x^{2}+3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Nobody has math symbols in the keyboard. You just need to learn to use MathJax. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $f(x)={1\over x^2+3}$ means $f({\rm anything})={1\over{\rm anything}^2+3}$. So if $g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$, then what is $f(g(x))$?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ means that whatever you plug into $f$... the result will be $1$ divided by the sum of whatever that thing was squared plus three...  So... $f(\color{red}{5})=\frac{1}{\color{red}{5}^2+3}$ and $f(49)=\frac{1}{49^2+3}$... this is true even when those things are more complicated and not just numbers or $x$... such as $f(62y^2+y)=\frac{1}{(62y^2+y)^2+3}$ or.... and here's the punchline... $f(g(x))=\frac{1}{(g(x))^2+3}$

Comment: But I think the best idea is to ask your teacher for help. That's what teachers are paid to do.

Comment: `$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3}$`    `$g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$`

Comment: With regards to typing mathematics here... visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site.  While $\LaTeX$ isn't commonly introduced to students until late into college, it can really help improve the look of your work and is an invaluable tool to have moving forward.  No time like the present to start learning.  While some uses of TeX can indeed by quite complicated, most of the basic stuff is just surrounding with dollar signs and using names of functions.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Ill be using that in the future

Comment: @GerryMyerson That makes a lot of sense,  thank you. And yes, I did decide to reach out to my teacher as well after this! For some reason, doing so just slipped my mind.

Comment: Your definition of $f \circ g$ is fine, but something to be wary of in the future is that some books (*Topics In Algebra* by Herstein is one) actually define it the other way around, i.e. $f  \circ g(x) = g(f(x))$.  I think books like that are in the minority, but look out when you pick up a new book.

Comment: @Mark anybody using Vim keybindings _has_ math symbols right on the keyboard. `(f ∘ g) with g(x) = √(x-2)` can be typed `(f {ctrl+k O b} g) with g(x) = {ctrl+k R T}(x-2)`. — Of course, MathJax gives more visually appealing results than plain Unicode though.

Answer (score 6):

The notation $(f \circ g)(x)$ means the same thing as $f(g(x))$. We are told that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ for all values of $x$. We can rewrite this by saying that $f(y)=\frac{1}{y^2+3}$ for all values of $y$. In particular, if $y=g(x)$, then
$$
f(y)=f(g(x))=\frac{1}{g(x)^2+3} \, .
$$
Since $g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$, we find that
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x-2}\right)^2+3}=\frac{1}{(x-2)+3}=\frac{1}{x+1} \, .
$$
Hence, option (c) is correct. Here is another way to understand this result. The notation $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ just means
$$
f(\text{something})=\frac{1}{\text{something}^2+3} \, .
$$
In particular, if that "something" equals $g(x)$, then we get that
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{1}{g(x)^2+3} \, ,
$$
and we arrive at the same result as before. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this step by step, replacing the x with y and then comparing y to g(x) made this all make so much more sense. I understand now, thanks! Is it always a situation where you would replace the x in whatever f(x) equals with g(x) in these problems, or should I be ready to figure out another way of solving?

Comment: @GraciousBean: Yes, if you are told that $f(x)=\text{some formula involving $x$}$, then to find $f(g(x))$ you can always just replace every occurence of $x$ with $g(x)$, and that's the easiest method. For example, if $f(x)=5x^2+27$ for all values of $x$, then $f(2^x)=5(2^x)^2+27$. All we had to do is this: wherever we see an $x$, replace it with $2^x$. That's it!

Comment: I think what can be confusing is that when given () = … and () = …, those are _not the same _.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3},$$

$$g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}.$$

$(f\circ g) (x)\ $ means the same as $\ f(g(x))\ = f(\sqrt{x-2}) = \ldots$

Can you continue this working?